# Is there an Android web browser which can upload files from a local file system?

Tags: file-system

I am considering buying and Android tablet and want to know if this function is possible.

Comment: I would assume all of them (or at least the major ones like stock, Firefox, Opera, and Dolphin).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stock android browser, as long as the website uses a file upload control it can.

I just used the upload tool on twitpic, which uses flash, allows me to select audio, video or image files, and uploads them to twitpic.

Comment: imgur.com, flickr are notable examples of sites that allow access natively for Android 2.2+.

Answer (score -3):

uc browser is the best for uploading files on the internet in  a file uploading website

Comment: UC Browser pays malware to advertise and install it after hacking your phone. That's how they get their ratings. Don't trust it.